Tate cohomology as a derived functor
I am trying to understand in what sense Tate cohomology may be regarded as the co-fibre of the norm map, from the perspective of derived functors.
Say $G$ is a finite group and $M$ is a $G$-module over a ring $R$. Group cohomology is $\mathrm{RHom}_G(R[G], M)$. Group homology is $R\otimes_{R[G]}^{\mathbb{L}}M$.
It is said that Tate cohomology is the co-fibre of the norm map, which is a natural transformation from the co-invariants functor to the invariants functor. $\mathrm{Hom}$ being a co-variant left exact functor, makes $\mathrm{RHom}$ computed using an injective resolution, while tensor product is right exact, making derived co-invariants being computed using a projective resolution.
Given a module $M$, the norm map is a map $N: M_G\to M^G$, and its co-fibre is the functor $M\mapsto M^G/N(M_G)$. Let's call this functor the Tate functor, and denote it by $T$. Can Tate cohomology be realised as the derived functors of $T$ with respect to some resolution?

Not exactly what you're asking, but if you take $M_{hG}$ and $M^{hG}$, then there is a map $M_{hG} \to M^{hG}$ whose cofibre is usually denoted $M^{tG}$ (the Tate construction). This makes sense in many stable $\infty$-categories (I forget if you need to work with "genuine" $G$-objects here), and in $D(R)$ if $M$ lives in degree $0$ gives the usual thing since $M_{hG}$ and $M^{hG}$ are fancy ways to write $R\otimes^{\mathbf L}_{R[G]} M$ and $\mathrm{RHom}_G(R[G],M)$. I'm guessing you came across all of this and are asking for a 1-categorical explanation in terms of abelian categories, right?

Of course, understanding this 1-categorically is kind of tricky because $(-)^G/N((-)_G)$ is neither left nor right exact. I suppose that does not a priori keep it from having left and right derived functors, but it's not so clear to me if these exist and what they mean. It would indeed be interesting if someone else can shed some light on this.

@R.vanDobbendeBruyn There's nothing thicky in deriving non-exact functors in old plain (and trusty) 1-categorical language. Moreover, there's a precise criterion for existense. See my answer and comments below https://mathoverflow.net/a/461097/81055 Derived functors of nonexact functor still serve the same exact role — being solutions to the Kan extension problem.

Alas, Tate cohomology is not a "classical derived functor" because it is nonzero (and even determined by) its values on acyclic complexes; so it is not a functor between (classical) derived categories. Still, you can define it via Buchweitz(-Orlov) equivalence: the stable category (not in infinity sense, but in representation-theoretical one) of $\Bbb Z [G]$-modules (also known as "singularity category") is equivalent to the homotopy category of acyclic complexes with injective-relative-to-$\Bbb Z$ terms.

So, Tate cohomology/Tate Ext functor (if LHS is $\Bbb Z$-free) can be compluted as a honest Hom-complex between those acyclic relatively injective resolutions.

@DenisT why not write an answer with some details of the argument you have in mind?

@R.vanDobbendeBruyn Well, writing a good answer takes significant effort (at least for me; I usually make a lot of slight misprints/errors, and it's hard to expunge them). General approach is already sketched. /// If someone is willing to make a comprehensible text out of my remarks (including future me), I think it would be nice to include Beilinson's approach via adjunction between $ZG$-modules and modules over orbit category; and on the orbit modules Tate cohomology becomes left exact. There was a link to his lecture notes somewhere on MO...
